# Review audit question failure - need to understand

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I was dinged for an inappropriate downvote on this audit question

[Find duplicate in array with a memory efficient approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078140/find-duplicate-in-array-with-a-memory-efficient-approach)

I downvoted it because it doesn't ask a question, and shows no effort.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Thanks for the possible dup suggestion, I have read several and was hoping for some specific advice about this particular question.

Comment: The duplicate does answer that: the question has a lot of upvotes so the system thinks it's a good question, which causes downvoting to fail the audit.

Comment: That being said, I disagree with your assessment. There is an implied question being asked here ("how do you implement such an algorithm"), and there is some research effort considering OP did try a solution but it wasn't adequate.

Comment: SO users like programming puzzles, much more so than the usual "debug my code" and "google this for me" crap that they typically encounter.  The question got a lot of views, and thus votes, it is not entirely obvious why.  While it might have skirted the "Hot Network Questions" list, I think the many edits of the answers could have re-activated the question repeatedly.  Giving the thumbs-down on a post that got so many helpful votes is only a good way to fail an audit.  You have to look, the one thing an audit checks.

Comment: Yes, I get that @HansPassant - I guess I need to understand the logic behind the audit mechanism some more and maybe use the 'Skip' button a bit if I'm not inclined to peek at a suspected audit question.